# I cannot find out why compiler reported the error?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

W = tf.Variable([0,3], dtype = tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-0.3], dtype = tf.float32)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

x_train = [1,2,3,4]
y_train = [0,-1,-2,-3]

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train, {x: x_train, y: y_train})

curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W,b,loss], {x: [1,2,3,4], y: [0,-1,-2,-3]})
print("w: %s, b: %s, loss: %s", curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss)
```

ERROR:InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [2] vs. [4]
     [[Node: mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable/read, _recv_Placeholder_0)]]

Comment: Instead of [0,3] (has a comma), do you actually mean [0.3] ?

Comment: Oh that reallt helpful THX!

Answer (score 2):

i guess the problem is here 
instead of this in W as you are using float32

```
W = tf.Variable([0,3], dtype = tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-0.3], dtype = tf.float32)
```

it will be

```
W = tf.Variable([0.3], dtype = tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-0.3], dtype = tf.float32)
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! This is really a detailed error, THX dude!